# Issue with log4j log not writing to file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

Does anyone see why this log is not writing to file.  It is writing to standard out twice but not to the file:

Also, I tried removing the "Stdout" appender and then I don't get any logging at all.

```
package org.berlin.wicket;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(QuickstartPage.class);
LOG.info("Loading constructor");
```

> log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,Stdout,mainAppender
>
> log4j.appender.Stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>   log4j.appender.Stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>
> log4j.appender.Stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%-5p - %-26.26c{1} -
>   %m\n
>
> log4j.appender.mainAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
>
> log4j.appender.mainAppender.file=logs/core.log
>
> log4j.appender.mainAppender.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
>
> log4j.appender.mainAppender.append=true
>
> log4j.appender.mainAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>
> log4j.appender.mainAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MM/dd/yyyy
>   HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%C{1}.%M():%L] [%t] [%p] - %m%n
>
> log4j.logger.org.berlin=DEBUG,Stdout,mainAppender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two loggers which use the same appender (Stdout), hence why you see entries on the console twice.

As others have mentioned, the properties are case-sensitive, hence why your file appender is not configured correctly.

Comment: I am not following the first part.  Which two loggers are pointing to the same appender?  RootLogger and logger.org.berlin? / log4j.logger.org.berlin=DEBUG,Stdout,mainAppender?

Comment: Yes -- the rootLogger and org.berlin are both using Stdout as an appender. I suspect this duplication is why you see two console writes.

Comment: Cool, I modified and it is working.  I also changed the file path to full file path.

Answer (score 2):

The `File` and `Append` properties are case senstive.

`log4j.appender.mainAppender.File=someFileName.log
log4j.appender.mainAppender.Append=true`

Answer (score -4):

You should create an instance of FileHandler that writes log to a file called myfile.log.

```
FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler("myfile.log", true);        
logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
```

Comment: Should?  Or could?  I have never done that for log4j before.  That would mean I have to add several more lines of logging through out all of my code.  Do you see an issue with my log4j.properties file

Comment: I don't see an issue with your log4j.properties file. Is your log file created?

Comment: I think it was actually the "file" path I was using.